# setting elements at specified indexes within ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an arraylist in which i want to set another array list at positions [0] and [1] every time.For example my arraylist has index [5] and [6].I want to set another array list at the above positions at index positions [0] and [1] on both.How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `set(index, element)` function. For Example, `list.set(0, object)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method of `ArrayList`.

> `public E set(int index, E element)`
>
> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.